# calling angular2 component function from sigma.js bind events

Tags: angular, events, sigma.js

I have a simple function in my angular2 component as follows:

```
onSelectNode(label: String) {
console.log(label)
// do something based on label
  }
```

and have created a basic sigma.js graph in angular2 as follows:

```
var s = new sigma({
  graph: sigmaJson,
  container: 'network-graph',
  settings: {
    defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
  }
});
```

My graph is getting rendered successfully. Now I want to call the function onSelectNode when one of the node is clicked. So, I have used the `bind` functionality as follows:

```
s.bind('clickNode', nodeClick)
```

The function nodeClick is defined as follows:

```
nodeClick(event) {
this.selectedLabel = event.data.node.label
console.log(this.selectedLabel)   // this prints correctly
this.onSelectNode(this.selectedLabel)  // getting error here
```

}

But I am not able to call the component function from within the `nodeClick` function. I am getting the following error in javascript console:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.onSelectNode is not a function
```

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was using the wrong `this` scope variable as pointed in [first comment here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/918). 
Ended up make the following change in the code and it worked:

1. Save the current `this` context in a separate variable before the callback function.

   `var self = this;`
2. Modified the code as follows:

   `s.bind('clickNode', function (e) {
     console.log(e.type, e.data.node.label, e.data.captor);
     self.selectedLabel = e.data.node.label;
     self.OnSelectNode(self.selectedLabel);
   });`